# Clickhouse Error [160] [07000]: Code: 160. DB::Exception: Estimated query execution time is too long

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I need query data in 24 hr interval. But receive limitation error

```
SQL Error [160] [07000]: Code: 160. DB::Exception: Estimated query execution time (60.01676629858564 seconds) is too long. Maximum: 60. Estimated rows to process: 1007022849: While executing MergeTreeThread. (TOO_SLOW)
```

Which is possible ways to optimize my query ?
max_execution_time on server have limit= 60s

```
set max_execution_time=60;
select name,article , sum(byteSize(message))  as size_in_bytes
    from stage.log_table
    where time >= '2022-11-03 00:00:00'
    and time   <= '2022-11-04 00:00:00'
    and (article like '%job%' or article like '%node%')
    and direction = 0
    group by name , article 
order by size_in_bytes desc
```

Also this query works on time interval = 15 hours.
So I tried to make a `union all`, but it still doesn't work.

```
set max_execution_time=60;
SELECT name,article,size_in_bytes from(
select name,article , sum(byteSize(message))  as size_in_bytes
    from stage.log_table
    where platform_time >= '2022-11-03 00:00:00'
    and platform_time   <= '2022-11-03 12:00:00'
    and (article like '%job%' or article like '%node%')
    and direction in 'In'
    group by name , article)
UNION ALL
SELECT name,article,size_in_bytes FROM ( select name,article , sum(byteSize(message))  as size_in_bytes
from stage.log_table
    where platform_time >= '2022-11-03 12:00:00'
    and platform_time   <= '2022-11-04 00:00:00'
    and (article like '%job%' or article like '%node%')
    and direction in 'In'
group by name , article)
```

Comment: why not increase it? besdes show the create table with indexes

Comment: please share SHOW CREATE TABLE stage.log_table, and use EXPLAIN to figure out